# How to accumulate SQL data using websocket with sqlalchemy on python

Tags: python, pandas, websocket, sqlalchemy, data-stream

I am using binance websocket to create sqlite database after closing of each candle on 1min interval. For this purpose I've create the following piece of code.

```
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from binance import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.enums import *
import sqlalchemy
import json
import random
import datetime
import time

engine= sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///app.db')
client = Client(api_public_key, api_private_key)
bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
socket = bsm.kline_socket('BTCUSDT', interval=KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE)

def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg['k']])
    df = df.loc[:, ['t', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'V']]
    df.columns = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    df.astype('float')
    df['time'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df['time'] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return df

while True:
    await socket.__aenter__()
    msg = await socket.recv()
    if msg['k']['x']:
        frame = createframe(msg)
        frame.to_sql(msg['k']['s'], engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Json object returned for kline websocket (msg):

```
{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1634470338549, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1634470320000, 'T': 1634470379999, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 'i': '1m', 'f': 1101708308, 'L': 1101708646, 'o': '61104.36000000', 'c': '61110.07000000', 'h': '61118.44000000', 'l': '61104.35000000', 'v': '5.48572000', 'n': 339, 'x': False, 'q': '335219.68678330', 'V': '3.23284000', 'Q': '197550.98708780', 'B': '0'}}
```

After running the code for few minutes I get the following output:

```
pd.read_sql('BTCUSDT',engine)



time                        open            high            low             close          volume
0   2021-10-17 06:27:00     61019.99000000  61020.00000000  61013.51000000  61015.01000000  3.07002000
1   2021-10-17 06:28:00     61015.00000000  61062.52000000  61000.01000000  61056.70000000  13.05177000
2   2021-10-17 06:28:00     61015.00000000  61062.52000000  61000.01000000  61056.70000000  13.05177000
3   2021-10-17 06:29:00     61056.71000000  61084.60000000  61053.57000000  61060.35000000  6.09200000
4   2021-10-17 06:29:00     61056.71000000  61084.60000000  61053.57000000  61060.35000000  6.09200000
5   2021-10-17 06:30:00     61060.35000000  61069.00000000  61050.00000000  61050.01000000  4.71704000
6   2021-10-17 06:30:00     61060.35000000  61069.00000000  61050.00000000  61050.01000000  4.71704000
7   2021-10-17 06:31:00     61050.01000000  61059.78000000  61000.00000000  61033.33000000  4.17527000
8   2021-10-17 06:31:00     61050.01000000  61059.78000000  61000.00000000  61033.33000000  4.17527000
9   2021-10-17 06:32:00     61033.33000000  61047.42000000  61013.00000000  61013.01000000  4.55346000
10  2021-10-17 06:33:00     61013.01000000  61040.36000000  61013.00000000  61024.17000000  12.86187000
11  2021-10-17 06:33:00     61013.01000000  61040.36000000  61013.00000000  61024.17000000  12.86187000
12  2021-10-17 06:34:00     61024.17000000  61024.18000000  60963.04000000  60967.06000000  7.99450000
```

Any idea on how to avoid timeframe data duplicates?

Comment: Store the `time` value in a variable on each iteration. If the current value is equal to the previous value then don't append the row.

Comment: I'm looking for more efficient way to do this. I don't want to store data which is problematic when you run it on small VMs.

Comment: I'm talking about storing a single `datetime` value. It's not a big deal.